# Can Auto Layout be used to replace Asset Catalog?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to ask what the purpose of using an asset catalog is, where one has to create x.png, x@2x.png, and x@3x.png images to support the iPhone screen platforms when they can just use Auto Layout?

I mean, can't we just setup constraints and have one x.png image, and depending on the screen size as well as the constraints, Auto Layout will scale the images proportionally without having to have 3 different size of the same images?

This is what I'm doing right now for my app, and want to know if it is beneficial to use Auto Layout instead of an Asset Catalog? Unless I'm misunderstanding the difference between the two?

[image]

As you can see from my screenshot, I setup an UIImageView with a proportional height constraint that will scale appropriately depending on the screen size.

Can someone explain in more details? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto layout changes size of image *view* (UIImageView). Asset catalog helps substitute different resolution *image* (UIImage) to match resolution of screen. They have nothing to do with one another.

Also, it is very wasteful of memory to use a larger image than you need. So you could use a 3x image scaled down on a single-resolution screen iPad, but that would be terribly wasteful of memory - and might not even look as good as using a single-resolution image to start with, where the pixels of the image can match the pixels of the screen.

Comment: I see, so for example I have an Asset labeled "close", and I have the appropriate image files close.png, close@2x.png, and close@3x.png. If I set the image view with the image "close", Xcode will know to choose the appropriate image file depending on iPhone screen size?

Comment: Not the screen size. The screen resolution. - This used to be done through the name of the image, but using the asset catalog is much easier. For what we used to have to do, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW8

Comment: thanks matt!....one last question, what is the drawback if I didn't use asset catalog, and provided Xcode with one image of the same resolution for all iPhone platforms?

Comment: Do you understand what resolution is?

Comment: no I didn't read all your answer, sorry my mind is not here right now, I just read your first paragraph (knocks head), my apology and thanks for the explanation :)